# Probability of picking X balls without replacement, what is the probability of having N<X consecutive balls of the same color?

Tags: probability

Suppose a bag contains 42 **red** balls and 86 **blue** balls (total 128). If we randomly pick 64 without replacement, what is the probability of having a set that contains at least **3 consecutive red** balls?

This problem can be solved by computing all possible strings of length 64 that satisfy the condition of having at max 42 red balls. Then, count the number of strings which contains a substring 'rrr'. However, I was wondering if this problem can easily be solve without a program?

I'm not sure how to calculate the number of permutations of length 64 in which we have at least a substring of 'rrr'?

Comment: Well, I'd do it recursively (on a computer).  The string must start with one of $B,RB, RRB$ or $RRR$ so either you are done (if you get $RRR$) or you restart with smaller numbers for which you can repeat the recursive argument.

Comment: Yes indeed. That is precisely how I'm calculating it now. But is there a way to calculate this number without a program?

Comment: Well, I'm skeptical.  Anything's possible, but it feels like a numerical problem to me.  If the numbers were a lot larger, I'd simply sample the system.